# Linking mac framework in VScode

Tags: macos, opengl, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm struggling to build an openGL project in VScode on Mac. The problem is how to add a framework in the tasks.json file of VScode. I can build the project successfully from the command line.

To build successfully I need the gcc command to include the argument -framework OpenGL. So it should read:

gcc *.cc -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g -framework OpenGL ...(etc.)

but if I add "-framework OpenGL" to the argument list in tasks.json, VScode parses it as:

gcc *.cc -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g '-framework openGL' ...(etc.)

Obviously gcc doesn't recognise '-framework OpenGL' in the inverted commas. 
How do I add a framework in VSCode on a mac???

My tasks.json is:

```
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            // "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "command": "gcc",
            "args": [
                "${fileDirname}/*.cc",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",  
                "-g",
                "-framework openGL",
                "-L/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/lib",
                "-L/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib/",
                "-lglfw",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Try putting them in separate rows like this:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-v",
            "-I/usr/local/include/GLFW",
            "-L/usr/local/lib",
            "-lglfw3",
            "-framework", 
            "Cocoa",
            "-framework",
            "OpenGL",
            "-framework",
            "IOKit"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

So:

```
"-framework", 
"Cocoa",
```

Answer (score 2):

Even my answer comes 4 years later I hope will help you.
The solution is to write the **c_cpp_properties.json** file (found or created by yourself in hidden .vscode folder inside your project) such as:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "go2sh.cmake-integration"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

As you can see, you have to add there this magic sentence:

```
"macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
```

Of course this is the path where my system keeps all the frameworks. You have to find and to fill your own system path.